# Integrating GoogleCast SDK with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-cast

We are having some trouble integrating GoogleCast SDK for iOS v3.3.0 via Cocoapods.

Running 'pod install' installs the pod just fine, and it also builds and runs the project without issue, but when the app launchs on the device, it crashes with this message:

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/735F9E66-D710-4E36-937D-50146F67B4DC/xxx.app/xxx
  Reason: image not found

We have researched the subject thoroughly but we're stalled at this point.

Thanks, greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried what you say.

Using an iPhone 6 and cocoapods 1.2.0 seems to be building and running perfectly.

I've made a test here: https://github.com/alextarrago/gcasttestcocoapods

Comment: After posting the question, I realized that I was on 1.1.1 and updated to 1.2, but still no luck. Also tried with the castvideos-ios demo and got the same error.

Comment: Did you check the test on github? Is this not running on your device?

Comment: No, I'm going to try now and will update with the result, thanks!

Comment: Yes, the code from github runs ok, we will investigate with the help of this project what we are missing, thanks!